# Load image and video data with Json and Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying do add data with Ajax/Json to this section. One is video and other two are images. I tried something like this from j query websites but there is no example there with video and images so i can't tell is that even posible or do i need to send two request to some json file. Can someone help?

```html
<section class="data">
    <div class="row slides">
        <div class="span-4">
            <video src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="span-4">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="span-4">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```js
$.getJSON( "js/data.json", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
    });

    $("<div>", {
        class: "my-data", 
        html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo(".data");
});
```

Comment: What is your JSON result?

Comment: Where is JSON date? Is it on your server?

Comment: its on local computer it's two arrays with data on it.

Comment: In first you need to check that `data` variable has content. Check it using console.

Answer (score 0):

In my view this can be achieved if you bring image and video path together in JSON. Maybe this [link](http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/08/create-html-table-using-jquery-ajax.html) can help you out with actual implementation. However the example is without image or video, but with plain json data and ajax.